# Angular.js second controller does not work.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="storeController as store">
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="product in store.product">
        <h3>
            {{product.name}}
            <em class="pull-right"> {{product.price | currency}}</em>
        </h3>
        <section ng-controller="tabController as tabCtrl">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li ng-class="{active:tab===1}"> <a href ng-click="tabCtrl.setTab(1)"> Description</a> </li>
                <li ng-class="{active:tab===2}"> <a href ng-click="tab =2"> Reviews</a> </li>
                <li ng-class="{active:tab===3}"> <a href ng-click="tab =3"> Specs</a> </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 1">
                <h4> Description</h4>
                <p>{{product.description}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 2">
                <h4> Reviews</h4>
                <blockquote>Not yet</blockquote>
            </div>
            <div class="panel" ng-show="tab === 3">
                <h4> Specifications</h4>
                <blockquote>Not yet</blockquote>
            </div>

        </section>
    </li>
</ul>



</body>
</html>
```

And here is the app.js that has the Angular Module and controllers :

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module("store",[]);
var gem = [
    {
    name: "Dodec",
    price: 2.95,
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false
    },
    {
    name: "Panta",
    price: 20.4,
    canPurchase: true,
    soldOut: false
    }
];
app.controller("storeController",function(){
    this.product = gem;
});

app.controller("tabController",function(){
    this.tab = 1;
    this.SetTab = function(value){
        this.tab = value;
    };
});


})();
```

The problem is the HTML is not reading the second controller, tabController, and therefore this.tab = 1 is not initializing tab to 1 , neither does the setTab function work.

PLease help, what did I get wrong  ?

Comment: well, try using $scope rather than .this and see if it helps ($scope.tab = 1; $scope.SetTab = ...) I know that angular 1.3 supports this.variable notation, but change the code to see if it works.

Comment: Yup it worked like that, thanks a ton. I can't seem to upvote your answer !

Comment: can you to say, where you get this pattern, please? putting data to controller directly?

Comment: I got it from codeschool videos. Is it a bad pattern?

Comment: Better to use `$scope` for this. It's more `angular way`. I simple see here(on `SO`) many questions with this pattern today)

Comment: Codeschool. I love their song in `node.js` lessons :)

Comment: The pattern is allowed, but it's new in angular 1.3 (controller as), so most people still use $scope because they know it, and using controller as is unfamiliar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an "answer", but more of a best practice when using "this". You might want to initialize 'this' to a variable and modify it later in the controller as such to make sure you are in the correct scope.

Ex:

```
app.controller("storeController",function(){
    var self = this;
    self.product = gem;
});

app.controller("tabController",function(){
    var self = this;
    self.tab = 1;
    self.SetTab = function(value){
        self.tab = value;
    };
});
```

Now, to address the question, try using $scope instead of 'this'

```
app.controller("storeController",function($scope){
    $scope.product = gem;
});

app.controller("tabController",function($scope){
    $scope.tab = 1;
    $scope.SetTab = function(value){
        $scope.tab = value;
    };
});
```

Comment: `self` is busy and sometimes used as current window/frame, better use some else. However, you just use your local variable and it matters little. I prefer `that`)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is quite simple: this is your `ngClick` handler:

```
ng-click="tabCtrl.setTab(1)"
```

and this is how you are defining controller function:

```
this.SetTab = function(value) {
    this.tab = value;
};
```

Note, that in javascript `setTab` is not the same as `SetTab`.

Another problem. If you chose to go with controller as syntax you should also fix ngClass and ngShow directives to use controller instance `tab` property, rather then `$scope` property:

```
ng-class="{active: tabCtrl.tab === 3}"
```

and

```
<div class="panel" ng-show="tabCtrl.tab === 2">
    <h4>Reviews</h4>
    <blockquote>Not yet</blockquote>
</div>
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/8WOzHCuFaJzgSNTy5X0i?p=preview

Comment: Hi dfsq, which syntax do you think is more efficient?

Comment: I mean the $scope or the controller alias ?

Comment: I would use "controller as" syntax. But you can use $scope as well. I prefer your current way better.